# Sys.Date() is Ignoring System Timezone

Tags: r

I am trying to do some dynamic date/time calculations. I noticed that my date/time calculations are off by 12 hours. It seems like `Sys.Date()` ignores the system timezone and defaults to UTC although system timezone is set accurately.

Help for `Sys.Date()` states the following.

> **Details**
>
> Sys.time returns an absolute date-time value which can be converted to various time zones and may return different days.
>
> Sys.Date returns the current day in the current **time zone**.

When I check the system timezone I can see it is correctly set.

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "Pacific/Auckland"
```

In addition, `Sys.getlocale()` returns the following. It seems like everything is fine here too.

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252"
```

Getting timezone of `Sys.Date()` using `lubridate::tz()` returns the following.

```
> lubridate::tz(Sys.Date())
[1] "UTC"
```

And, converting the `Sys.Date()` to a `POSIXct` confirms that the original timezone of `Sys.Date()` despite accurately set system timezone is UTC.

```
> as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
[1] "2019-07-15 12:00:00 NZST"
```

Initially, I thought maybe Sys.Date() is being overwritten by some other package. Restarting the R session does not change anything. Here is my `sessionInfo()`.

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] elasticsearchr_0.3.0 viridis_0.5.1        viridisLite_0.3.0    forecast_8.7        
 [5] extrafont_0.17       forcats_0.4.0        stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.3         
 [9] purrr_0.3.2          readr_1.3.1          tidyr_0.8.3          tibble_2.1.3        
[13] ggplot2_3.2.0        tidyverse_1.2.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zoo_1.8-6         tidyselect_0.2.5  urca_1.3-0        haven_2.1.1       lattice_0.20-38  
 [6] colorspace_1.4-1  generics_0.0.2    rlang_0.4.0       pillar_1.4.2      glue_1.3.1       
[11] withr_2.1.2       modelr_0.1.4      TTR_0.23-4        readxl_1.3.1      quantmod_0.4-15  
[16] timeDate_3043.102 munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_0.3.4      
[21] tseries_0.10-47   lmtest_0.9-37     curl_3.3          parallel_3.6.1    Rttf2pt1_1.3.7   
[26] broom_0.5.2       xts_0.11-2        Rcpp_1.0.1        scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.4  
[31] jsonlite_1.6      gridExtra_2.3     fracdiff_1.4-2    hms_0.4.2         stringi_1.4.3    
[36] grid_3.6.1        quadprog_1.5-7    cli_1.1.0         tools_3.6.1       magrittr_1.5     
[41] lazyeval_0.2.2    crayon_1.3.4      extrafontdb_1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.2   xml2_1.2.0       
[46] lubridate_1.7.4   assertthat_0.2.1  httr_1.4.0        rstudioapi_0.10   R6_2.4.0         
[51] nnet_7.3-12       nlme_3.1-140      compiler_3.6.1
```

Is anyone experiencing something similar? I feel like I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sys.Date` returns a Date object, which does not include a timezone attribute:

```
> str(Sys.Date())
Date[1:1], format: "2019-07-14"
```

`lubridate::tz` returns "UTC" if a timezone attribute does not exist:

```
function (x) 
{
    tzone <- attr(x, "tzone")[[1]]
    if (is.null(tzone) && !is.POSIXt(x)) 
        return("UTC")
    if (is.character(tzone) && nzchar(tzone)) 
        return(tzone)
    tzone <- attr(as.POSIXlt(x[1]), "tzone")[[1]]
    if (is.null(tzone)) 
        return("UTC")
    tzone
}
```

So it's not that `Sys.Date` ignores the system timezone; it's that the Date object does not include any timezone information, so you can't recover a timezone from a Date object.

Comment: Aha! I knew I was missing something. I could not make any proper conclusions because `Sys.Date()` was giving the correct date. I defaulted to using `lubridate()::tz()` because that is the only function I used to extract timezone information. Thank you for the speedy reply.